# angular app not working in rails environment after organising angular files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a rails app which uses angular. It is also using ui router for routing. I first had all js codes in app.js and it works well. But I think its very hard to maintain in the long run. So I moved the controllers code to its own folder and it stopped working. Now My app cant find my controller and getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module appname due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module homeCtrl due to:
```

I have created a test app to demonstrate this..
https://bitbucket.org/flyingboy007/testapp

Could some one tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: just remove `homeCtrl` dependency form `app.module.js`, because we don't need that there.

Answer (score 1):

just remove homeCtrl dependency form app.module.js, because we don't need that there.

```
angular.module("testapp", ['ui.router', 'templates', 'homeCtrl']);

to 

angular.module("testapp", ['ui.router', 'templates']);
```

Comment: Havent noticed that.. Now the error is gone but its not rendering the home.html page as expected

Comment: showing this `<ui-view class="ng-scope"></ui-view>`== $0

Comment: no errors on console and when I select inspect on chrome the above is shown

Comment: i clone your project and fix the problem but not able to push .

Comment: you must do a pull request instead

Comment: not able to push on bitbucket instead create new repo on github. clone this https://github.com/pardeep-netsol/angular_app

Comment: I have cloned your project and tried it but still same..Is it working for you?